# Solr combining exact match and likely match on single text field not working

Tags: solr

I am trying to perform likely search on full-name fields and exact match on office-no,mobile-number,house-no,other-phone-number fields .All these i have copied to Text field "full-search-all" so that i can configure into website for a single text box where users can search for full-name like Kat should return Katric and if they give exact mobile number as 123456789 on same text field should return exact match result. Either one(exact match on mobile,office,house numbers OR likely match on full-name) working for my "full-search-all" field when i perform search.Both of them not working on full-search-all field in solrAdmin. I am Stanadard Query Parser.

I have placed my schema.xml file which i have created for my search.

Please can you pointout where is the wrong in Schema.xml file . Both search won't be searchable on single text field?

Complete schema.xml file below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema name="dynamic" version="1.5">
    <types>
        <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
            <analyzer type="index">
                <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="15" />
            </analyzer>
            <analyzer type="query">
                <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
        <fieldType name="search" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
            <analyzer type="index">
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            </analyzer>
            <analyzer type="query">
                <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
        <fieldType name="exactstring" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
            <analyzer>
                <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
        <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true" />
        <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" />
    </types>
    <fields>
        <!-- The _version_ field is required when using the Solr update log or SolrCloud (cfr. SOLR-3432) -->
        <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" />
        <field name="full-search-all" type="search" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
        <field name="phone-number" type="exactstring" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
        <!-- Exact Match columns -->
        <copyField source="mobile-number" dest="phone-number" />
        <copyField source="house-no" dest="phone-number" />
        <copyField source="office-no" dest="phone-number" />
        <copyField source="other-phone-number" dest="phone-number" />
        <copyField source="mobile-number" dest="full-search-all" />
        <copyField source="house-no" dest="full-search-all" />
        <copyField source="office-no" dest="full-search-all" />
        <copyField source="other-phone-number" dest="full-search-all" />
        <copyField source="full-name" dest="full-search-all" />
        <!-- query fields -->
        <field name="application-id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="full-name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="mobile-number" type="exactstring" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="house-no" type="exactstring" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="office-no" type="exactstring" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="other-phone-number" type="exactstring" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="campaign-name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="reason" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
    </fields>
    <uniqueKey>application-id</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Field name only should consist of alphanumeric or underscore characters only and not start with a digit**

> The name of the field.  Field names should consist of alphanumeric or underscore characters only and not start with a digit. This is not currently strictly enforced, but other field names will not have first class support from all components and back compatibility is not guaranteed. Names with both leading and trailing underscores (e.g. *version*) are reserved. Every field must have a name.

**Most of your field name contain `-` character, remove the character.**

Source : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Defining+Fields

Once you have copied field into `full_search_all` field, you can't separate them from that field. So if you want name to be prefix, phone to be exact search you can't do this with a single field.

Instead write a query analyzer, which will tell you on which which field to perform search.

For example : If a user write `123456789` (only numeric) on the text box, your query analyzer should return field to search is `phone_number`.

Query will be:

```
phone_number : 123456789
```

And if a user write `ashraful` (non numeric) on the text box your query analyzer should return `full_name`.

Query will be :

```
full_name : ashraful
```

Comment: Ok sure .Will remove the - characters . Does it help my text field to perform both searchs like likely match and exact match from different fields.?

Comment: Hi, I have created likely search and mapped to full-name as below .But sorting not working for full-name fields in solr Admin UI.Below the xml file . I want to perform likely search on full-name and exact match on phone-number,office-no,house-no and sorting to be done on full-name,few more fields.Having issue in sorting full-name since i added NGramFilter factory. Added xml file with page

Comment: <fieldType name="likelyString" class="solr.TextField">
<analyzer> <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/><filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="30"/>
</analyzer></fieldType><fieldType name="String" class="solr.TextField"></fieldType>
<fields>
<field name="phone-number" type="String" indexed="true"/> 
<field name="office-no" type="String" indexed="true" /> 
<field name="full-name" type="likelyString" indexed="true"/>
<field name="reason" type="likelyString" indexed="true"/>